# Remove all item in Arraylist that corresponds to object in Remove method

Tags: android, arraylist

I'm currently facing a problem in which it doesn't remove the items which I provider in `remove` method.

```
ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

persons.add(new Person(1,"john","london"));
persons.add(new Person(1,"john","london"));
persons.add(new Person(1,"john","london"));
persons.add(new Person(1,"john","london"));
persons.add(new Person(2,"blaze","paris"));
persons.add(new Person(2,"blaze","paris"));

persons.remove(new Person(1,"john","london"));
```

The size of the Arraylist remains the same even I already removed an item.
How can I remove all items corresponding to the object I put inside `remove` method?

Answer (score 1):

The `List.remove()` method will scan the list trying to find an object which is equal to the one you passed in.  When you did this:

```
persons.add(new Person(1,"john","london"));
```

you added a new `Person` object named John London at a certain place in memory.  When you called

```
persons.remove(new Person(1,"john","london"));
```

you asked Java to search for a *second* `Person` object named John London located in a *different* location in memory.  Java could not find this object, and hence the size of your list remained the same.

To get the meme across, the following `if` comparison will return `false` using the default `equals()` method inherited from `Object`:

```
Person p1 = new Person(1, "john", "london");
Person p2 = new Person(1, "john", "london");
if (p1.equals(p2)) {
    System.out.println("they are equal");
}
```

**What you should do:**

If you want two people with the same id and name to be considered equal, then you will have to overload the `equals()` method of your `Person` class:

```
class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int id;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if ((o == null) || (getClass() != o.getClass())) {
            return false;
        }

        Person other = (Person)o;
        boolean result = firstName.equals(other.firstName) &&
                         lastName.equals(other.lastName) &&
                         id == other.id;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty bad or the information you posted is incomplete.
To remove an item from the list you need one of 2 options:

1. pass to the remove function the reference to the object you want to remove (and not a new object).
2. use the equals function in the Person class for the list to find which element should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

First as @Tim Biegeleisen pointed out you should override `Person.equals()`.

Then you can do a new method that finds the persons who matches your condition.

```
private List<Person> findPersons(ArrayList<Person> persons, Person personToMatch) {
    List<Person> personsFound = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Person person : persons) {
        if (person.equals(personToMatch) {
            personsFound.add(person);
        }
    }
    return personsFound;
}
```

Finally you can call:

```
List<Person> personsToRemove = findPersons(persons, new Person(1,"john","london"));
persons.removeAll(personsToRemove);
```